# Why is so much worse to call a place of an array than a variable

Tags: java, sorting

I'm starting with Java, and I just came up with this huge difference: why is making references to an array so much worse than assigning the value to a variable and then calling the variable? (If that's not the problem of my code, then what's the problem of my code?)

I tried to implement selection sort in Java and here I show you the times.

In my mind an array was like a list of symbolic variables so I don't see how is that much worse to call array items directly.

Here's the code (times below)

```
public static int[] selectionSort(int ... numbers) {
  int pos, value;
  int[] result = numbers.clone();
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
    value = result[i];
    pos = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
      if (result[j] < value) {
        value = result[j];
        pos = j;
      }
    }
    result[pos] = result[i];
    result[i] = value;
  }
  return result;
}

public static int[] selectionSortWorse(int ... numbers) {
  int pos, value;
  int[] result = numbers.clone();
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
    pos = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
      if (result[j] < result[pos]) {
        pos = j;
      }
    }
    value = result[pos];
    result[pos] = result[i];
    result[i] = value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

### Time comparison (average of 10) of `selectionSort` vs. `selectionSortWorse`

- length of array: 10000; times 33.14 ms vs. 52.33 ms
- length of array: 20000; times 127.13 ms vs. 207.46 ms
- length of array: 50000; times 793.56 ms vs. 1302.48 ms
- length of array: 100000; times 3096.43 ms vs. 5072.56 ms

Comment: Usually relevant: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Accessing an array element is a bit slower than accessing a simple variable and you do that a lot in this program. So you get a big difference.

Comment: The code of `result[pos]` loads two variables and does a more complicated address calculation, than the code of `value`. The condition means that the if-statement is not entered half of the time. With an other language like C one might expect optimized code generated. Typically a java compiler does not do this.

Comment: @JoopEggen The JIT might very much do such optimisations. But that depends on data size, and specific configuration parameters.

Comment: Accessing a variable: you have an address -> you access it. Accessing an array: you have an address of an array's beginning, need to calculate the data size, shift the address to the dataSize * elementNumber -> you access it.

Comment: @GhostCat yes, a good point. Though here 100_000 with a 2 s cost is a bit heavy.

Comment: I guess the results depends on how sorted the array on input is. If the condition `if (result[j] < value)` is true very often, the difference might decrease drastically.

Comment: If you look at the generated bytecode, your second version has an extra `ALOAD` (_retrieve object reference from local variable_) and `IALOAD` (_retrieve integer from array_) compared to your first version. If `result[pos]` had been a loop invariant, the compiler could've lifted the extra loads out of the inner loop, but that `pos = j` statement prevents that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing an array element, for example `result[pos]`, there is an overhead compared to accessing a direct variable, for example `value`, at least 2 more things have to happen:

- Verifying range, for the example, verifying that `pos >= 0 && pos < result.length`
- The address of the element needs to be calculated, something like "result address + (pos * element_size)" instead of just "value address". This shouldn't be significant, but if repeated enough might have an impact.